# How to split a string into 2 at the last occurrence of an underscore character

Tags: java, regex, string

Given a string with a number of underscore characters, how can it be split into two substrings around the last underscore character?

eg. "a_b_c" => ["a_b", "_c"]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf` on `String` which returns you the index of the last occurrence of a chain of caracters.

```
String thing = "132131_12313_1321_312";
int index = thing.lastIndexOf("_");
String yourCuttedString = thing.substring(0, index);
```

It returns `-1` if the occurrence is not found in the String.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`String#lastIndexOf(String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29), try :

```
int lastIndexOf = str.lastIndexOf("_");
String substring1 = str.substring(0, lastIndexOf);
String substring2 = str.substring(lastIndexOf+1, str.length());
```

Comment: `str.substring(lastIndexOf+1, str.length())` can also be written `str.substring(lastIndexOf+1)` directly.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
    String[] a = s.split("_(?!.*_)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String last index of method, this returns an int, which you can then pass into the subString method.

```
String code = "123_456_789";
String subString = code.subString(code.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Comment: There is no `split` method that takes an `int` as an argument.

Comment: You are right, my bad I meant subString, will update to reflect that.